# Pfister bathroom faucet -- where to remove top part of hose from faucet?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

we're having trouble with a leak in the faucet hose. It seems to be leaking after the valve on the hot water side, local valve has been shut off.

I can see a nut where the hose connects to the valve on the bottom end of the hose, but where does the top part of hose connect to the faucet (to remove and replace the hose)?

Thanks

[image: View from underneath sink. Doesn't look like there's a nut to unscrew the hose from?]

[image: Hose connection to valve]

[image: Pfister logo, have not been successful at prying off]

[image: Faucet view from top]

Comment: I couldn’t guess your faucet model or product line, but I did google up Pfister single handle bath faucets parts diagrams and see that at least some Pfister’s come hoses attached, meaning it maybe easiest to replace the entire faucet.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the flexihose is crimped on the to faucet lines but it's very hard to see on the first image, there seems to be a brass coloured hexagonal piece at the end of the pipe but based on the image I'm unable to tell if it's a crimp or screw fitting.

What would be best at this point is to remove the faucet by disconnecting the hot and cold water flexihoses from your valves and unscrewing the faucet's mounting bolt.
Once you've got the faucet out you can take a closer look at the flexihose connection.

The you'll most likely have one of two situations:

- Either the flexihose is crimped on and it will probably be best to replace the whole faucet.
- Or if you're lucky it will be a screw-in flexihose which can be removed, remove the flexihose and take it to your local hardware store to get a replacement hose. After that it's just a matter of screwing the new flexihose on and mounting the faucet back to the sink.

If you've removed the tap check to make sure the gasket between the tap and the sink is still ok or if it also needs replacing. (Sometimes a good cleaning is enough though!) This will help prevent water leaking down from the top.